# I can't get the first if statement to work in the loop.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create this simple code for a class project. When I typed in the first if statement, my equations no longer worked but the if statement to trigger the "you are done" and break statements work. Taking out the first if statement causes my equations to work but i can't end the program. Is there any way to get around this?

```
   # input [4, 6, 12, 9, 1, 2]
    S = 0
    C = 0
    X = 999
    while True:
        Xstring = raw_input("Please Enter a Number: ")
        if Xstring == int(X):
            X = int(Xstring)
            S = S + X
            C = C + 1
            print C
            if C > 0:
                A = S / C
                print A
        elif Xstring == (""):
            print str('You are done.')
            break
```

Comment: raw_input is returning a string, so Xstring is a string.  X is an int.  Converting an int to an int does nothing.  So you're then comparing an int to a string and they're very different things

Comment: I suggest you read a few tutorials, a string is already a `str` , also `elif Xstring` is sufficient to check for an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it backwards. It should be `if int(Xstring) == X`. You also don't need to do `X = int(Xstring)` because the `if` statement already established that they're equal. Also, `C > 0` will always be `True` because it starts at `0` and only goes up.

Comment: thank you! I changed the first if statement to 'if Xstring != (""):' and made the elif statement an 'else:' and it all came together.

Comment: @IxiusRoulee if that's what you wanted you can change that `if` statement to simply `if Xstring:`.